# Php find time intervals between two timestamp

Tags: php, time, between

I have three variable.

**First**: **Start date** stamp and its string value(04.10.2015 13:30:00)
**Second**: **End date** stamp and its string value(04.10.2015 18:30:00)
**Interval**: **Time interval minutes** and its integer value(20)

I want to find all times between this timestamps each 20 minutes. 
Like:

> 04.10.2015 13:30:00
>   04.10.2015 13:50:00
>   04.10.2015 14:10:00
>   04.10.2015 14:30:00
>   04.10.2015 14:50:00
>   04.10.2015 15:10:00
>   04.10.2015 15:30:00
>   04.10.2015 15:50:00
>   04.10.2015 17:10:00
>   04.10.2015 17:30:00
>   04.10.2015 17:50:00
>   04.10.2015 18:10:00
>   04.10.2015 18:30:00

How can i do this,

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
for($i = strtotime('04-10-2015 13:30:00'); $i <= strtotime('04-10-2015 18:30:00'); $i += 1200) {
    echo date('d m Y H:i:s', $i) . '<br />';
}
```

1200 = 20 Mins * 60 Seconds

Answer (score -1):

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```